# Pausing a child process in C

Tags: c, signals

In my C program I'm trying to pause the state of a child process created by execl when the user input is 'p'. I have two terminals one for input which is the parent and another for output which is the child process. I have signal handlers in the child process that the parent can send to in order to increase and decrease the speed at which its output. I tried doing

```
kill(child_pid,SIGSTOP)
```

but this just stops both the child and the parent.

As of now in order to pause I have signal_handlers saving the current speed then changing the speed to 2147483647 seconds then when they resume it puts the saved speed back. Is this reasonable?(That is approx. 68 years and I have it in a while loop)

Sent output to other terminal with code below.

```
static state* start_button(void)
{
    state *destination;                                                        

    pid_t pid;                                                    
    pid = fork();                                                 
    switch(pid)                                                   
    {                                                                          
        case -1:                                   
            destination = &ready;                                              
            break;                                                             
        case 0:                                                                          
            execl("./outputTerminal",
                "outputTerminal",file_number,"/dev/ttys001",NULL);                                                                     
            break;                                                             
        default:                                                               
            destination = &going;                                            
            break;                                                             
    }                                                                          

    return destination;
 }
```

Comment: How did you make the stdout of the child process be the second terminal ? Do you mind to share your code ? what do you mean by `I have signals` ? And what did you expect `SIGSTOP` signal to do ? this signal can't be ignored and stops the execution of the receiving process...

Comment: What I meant by I have signals is I created signal handlers using SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2. I was hoping SIGSTOP would just stop the process created by exec and keep the main process still going @TonyTannous

Comment: Is it possible my child_pid is 0 for whatever reason when I call sigstop?

Comment: actually that is exactly what my problem is ^

Comment: No. Pid 0 is the pid of the wrapper process. The reason though the value of `int pid` is 0. That has to do with fork return value. Which is 0 to child process and the pid of the new process to the parent process.

Comment: I think I know what to do now, create a variable that stores getpid() of the child?

Comment: You have the pid of the child stored in `int pid` in parent. I don't know how to make things faster/slower by sending signals and I don't understand what you are trying to achieve... so I can't answer your question. But if you want to get the pid of the child then in the switch, in default if you print the value of `pid_t pid` it is the pid of child process.

Comment: I got it working. I just wanted to stop the child process. What I was doing before was trying to access a variable in the child process from my parent so it was always 0.

Comment: Glad my comments helped you.

Comment: The insane thing is, was for the longest time I was using a pid that was 0 but it still changed how my child was running the way I was handling things which led me to believe it was the right pid. >_<